# How to solve this error in Arduino code ESP32 Board + PS4 controller

Tags: arduino

In the end of this error message there is "exit status1"

Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

Could somebody explain me what it means (cause of it) and how to solve it ?

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"

Compiling core...
Using precompiled core:
C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_137710\core\core_faddaac1d69e7dde1f9d30f3045a530a.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\1.22.0-97-gc752ad5-5.2.0/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc" -nostdlib "-LC:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6/tools/sdk/lib" "-LC:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6/tools/sdk/ld" -T esp32_out.ld -T esp32.project.ld -T esp32.rom.ld -T esp32.peripherals.ld -T esp32.rom.libgcc.ld -T esp32.rom.spiram_incompatible_fns.ld -u esp_app_desc -u ld_include_panic_highint_hdl -u call_user_start_cpu0 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-static -Wl,--undefined=uxTopUsedPriority -u __cxa_guard_dummy -u __cxx_fatal_exception -Wl,--start-group
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\sketch\Pokus_o_Arduino_PS4_a_GPIO-23_50Hz_1000-2000us_do_ODrivu.ino.cpp.o"
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\ESP32Servo\ESP32PWM.cpp.o"
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\ESP32Servo\ESP32Servo.cpp.o"
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\ESP32Servo\ESP32Tone.cpp.o"
"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\ESP32Servo\analogWrite.cpp.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4.c.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_parser.c.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_spp.c.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\PS4Controller.cpp.o"

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_137710\core\core_faddaac1d69e7dde1f9d30f3045a530a.a" -lgcc -lesp_websocket_client -lwpa2 -ldetection -lesp_https_server -lwps -lhal -lconsole -lpe -lsoc -lsdmmc -lpthread -llog -lesp_http_client -ljson -lmesh -lesp32-camera -lnet80211 -lwpa_supplicant -lc -lmqtt -lcxx -lesp_https_ota -lulp -lefuse -lpp -lmdns -lbt -lwpa -lspiffs -lheap -limage_util -lunity -lrtc -lmbedtls -lface_recognition -lnghttp -ljsmn -lopenssl -lcore -lfatfs -lm -lprotocomm -lsmartconfig -lxtensa-debug-module -ldl -lesp_event -lesp-tls -lfd -lespcoredump -lesp_http_server -lfr -lsmartconfig_ack -lwear_levelling -ltcp_transport -llwip -lphy -lvfs -lcoap -lesp32 -llibsodium -lbootloader_support -ldriver -lcoexist -lasio -lod -lmicro-ecc -lesp_ringbuf -ldetection_cat_face -lapp_update -lespnow -lface_detection -lapp_trace -lnewlib -lbtdm_app -lwifi_provisioning -lfreertos -lfreemodbus -lethernet -lnvs_flash -lspi_flash -lc_nano -lexpat -lfb_gfx -lprotobuf-c -lesp_adc_cal -ltcpip_adapter -lstdc++ -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-EL -o

"C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658/Pokus_o_Arduino_PS4_a_GPIO-23_50Hz_1000-2000us_do_ODrivu.ino.elf"

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o:(.literal.gapInitService+0x1c): undefined reference to `GAP_ConnOpen'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o:(.literal.gapEventHandle+0xc): undefined reference to `GAP_ConnGetL2CAPCid'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o:(.literal.gapEventHandle+0x10): undefined reference to `GAP_ConnBTRead'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o:(.literal.gapSendHid+0x14): undefined reference to `GAP_ConnBTWrite'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o: In function `gapInitService':

C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\src/ps4_gap.c:48: undefined reference to `GAP_ConnOpen'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o: In function `gapUpdateConnected':

C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\src/ps4_gap.c:48: undefined reference to `GAP_ConnGetL2CAPCid'

C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\src/ps4_gap.c:48: undefined reference to `GAP_ConnGetL2CAPCid'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o: In function `gapEventHandle':

C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\src/ps4_gap.c:48: undefined reference to `GAP_ConnBTRead'

C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_197658\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\ps4_gap.c.o: In function `gapSendHid':

C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3\src/ps4_gap.c:88:
undefined reference to `GAP_ConnBTWrite'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Using library ESP32Servo at version 0.9.0 in folder: C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP32Servo

Using library PS4-esp32-master-AED3 at version 2.0 in folder: C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PS4-esp32-master-AED3

exit status 1

Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

Comment: Try switching to esp32 1.0.4 and re-test. Also check [this](https://github.com/jvpernis/esp32-ps3/issues/26)

Comment: Thank you very much :) This helped....  don't you know how is it possible that newer version of ESP32 board driver isn't working properly ?

Comment: undefined reference to `GAP_ConnBTWrite

Answer (score 2):

What version of your Arduino IDE? I already had this error using version 1.5.x, so I reinstalled for version 1.6.x and the code compiled.

This kind of linker (ld) error generally means that the functions were declared (probably in a header file) but they were not actually defined (usually done in a .cpp file). This is probably because the library did not get installed correctly and completely.